# warning :: invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt. What is the meaning and solution(s)?

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling, warnings

The following code is throwing the mysterious Warnings. I can't understand what they mean. What do these errors indicate and how to eradicate them?

```
require "conn.php";
$q = mysqli_stmt_init($dbconn);
$query = "SELECT users.userid FROM users WHERE users.email = ? ";
mysqli_stmt_prepare($q, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q, "s", $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($q);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($q);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    $q = mysqli_stmt_init($dbconn);
    $query = "INSERT INTO users ( users.first_name, users.last_name, users.mobile_no, users.email, users.password, users.reg_date) 
        VALUES (? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,NOW() )";
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($q, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q, "sssss", $first_name, $last_name, $mobile_number, $email, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($q);
    if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($q) == 1) {
        echo "data inserted <br>";
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
            echo "$key - - - > $val <br>";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "email is already registered";
}
```

whenever I run this block of code following warnings occur

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt in /storage/emulated/0/htdocs/registration_process.php on line 66

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt in /storage/emulated/0/htdocs/registration_process.php on line 67

Warning: mysqli_stmt_get_result(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt in /storage/emulated/0/htdocs/registration_process.php on line 68

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /storage/emulated/0/htdocs/registration_process.php on line 70
```

Comment: can you please show `registration_process.php` this file

Comment: that is a large page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is quite peculiar. It sounds unrelated but this error message is the result of *unreliable syntax variant*.

Procedural mysqli syntax is not only *excessively verbose* as compared to object syntax, but also deceptive, raising an error *not when it really occurs*, but when it's already too late, not to mention the cryptic nature of this error message.

There is some problem with your query and you need to get the **real** error message **from MySQL** as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param) but in order to implement it you have to change the syntax.

Takeaway: to solve your problem

1. rewrite your `conn.php` as shown in this my [article](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect#oop) to set the proper connection settings
2. rewrite your procedural mysqli to object syntax, such as

   ```
   $query = "SELECT userid FROM users WHERE email = ?";
   $stmt = $dbconn->prepare($query);
   $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
   $stmt->execute();
   $result = $stmt->get_result();
   ```
3. get **the real error message**
4. if the error is already clear then just fix it, or otherwise google for the better explanation

and after that you'll be able to fix the issue.